# Dynamic dispatch function call with variadic arguments

Tags: c++, c++14, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have some functions to support that all take homogenous arguments. But each function can take different number of them.
These functions are called by specifying the name of the function and its arguments.

Example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

enum class operation{
    abs,
    add,
    ceil,
    floor,
    sub
};

template <typename... T>
int foo(operation op, const T&... args){
    
    std::vector<int> operands({args...});
    
    switch(op){
        case operation::abs:
            return abs(operands[0]);
        case operation::add:
            return operands[0] + operands[1];
        case operation::ceil:
            return ceil(operands[0]);
        case operation::floor:
            return floor(operands[0]);
        case operation::sub:
            return operands[0] - operands[1];
    }
}

int main() {
    
    // operation is a user input at runtime
    operation op = operation::add;
    
    // call foo with some arguments
    std::cout << foo(op, 5, 6);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This has certain problems:

1. uses vector and hence there is unnecessary heap allocation.
2. Code bloat as all operations are compiled for different number of arguments.
3. A very large if/else as I keep adding operations.

Most of the related questions use function objects and template to tackle this. But here the operation is not known compile time constant.

Is there a better way to go about doing this without having to deal with compiling code for all operations in all instantiations of foo?

Comment: How is is that the operations are not known until run time, but the arguments of the operations are known at compile time?

Comment: `1` and `2` can be solved by not having a single variadic function, but instead one function per arity: `foo(op, arg)` to handle one-parameter operators, `foo(op, arg1, arg2)` to handle two-parameter ones. `3` can be solved by maintaining a mapping from `operation` values to function pointers (possibly again separate mappings per arity).

Answer (score 1):

https://godbolt.org/z/aKxsb18qe

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

enum class operation{
    abs,
    add,
    ceil,
    floor,
    sub
};

template <typename T, typename... J>
inline __attribute__((always_inline)) T GetFirstPack(T t, J... j)
{
    return t;
}

template <typename T1, typename... T>
int foo(operation op, const T1& arg, const T&... args){
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args) == 0)
    {
        switch(op)
        {
            case operation::abs:
                return abs(arg);
            case operation::ceil:
                return ceil(arg);
            case operation::floor:
                return floor(arg);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch(op){
            case operation::add:
                return arg + GetFirstPack(args...);

            case operation::sub:
                return arg - GetFirstPack(args...);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    
    // operation is a user input at runtime
    operation op = operation::add;
    
    // call foo with some arguments
    std::cout << foo(op, 5, 6);
    
    return 0;
}
```